# cannot launch node of type[turtlebot_teleop/turtlebot_teleop_key]

Tags: ros, roslaunch, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop;

```
error:cannot launch node of type[turtlebot_teleop/turtlebot_teleop_key]
```

I built the turtlebot pkgs from source ,I also sourced the workspace .In turtlebot_teleop file,other were roslaunch successfully! why?Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273555/cannot-launch-node-of-type%5Bturtlebot_teleop/turtlebot_teleop_key%5D/) by [lxz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32320/lxz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @lxz ,

you are forgetting the `.launch` extension of the launch file when calling `roslaunch`.

Your command should be: `roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch`

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0